# Move first letter for each word to the end and add a char, with condition

Tags: java, android, string

Okay, i will make it short.

This is my code

```
String s = edittextkata.getText().toString();
            String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u","A","I","U","E","O"};
            String firstLetter;
            if (s.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EMPTY, CAN NOT ENCRYPT!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (s.contains(" ")) {
                String[] wordArray = s.split(" ");
                firstLetter="";
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" ");
                outerloop:
                for(String word:wordArray){
                    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++){
                        if(word != null){
                        String words=wordArray[i].trim();
                        firstLetter+=(words.charAt(0));
                        input+=words.substring(1);
                        if(wordArray[i].startsWith(vowels[i]))
                        {
                            hasil=input+firstLetter+"IN"+" ";
                            sb.append(hasil);
                            i++;
                            continue outerloop;
                        } else{
                            hasil=input+firstLetter+"AN"+" ";
                            sb.append(hasil);
                            i++;
                            continue outerloop;
                        }}
                    }break outerloop;
                }
                sb.toString(); // Re-join string
                edittexthasil.setText(sb);
            } else {
                int i=0;
                firstLetter="";
                if(s.startsWith(vowels[i])){
                    firstLetter += s.charAt(0);
                    input = s.substring(1);
                    hasil = input + firstLetter + "IN";
                    edittexthasil.setText(hasil.toString());
                } else {
                    firstLetter += s.charAt(0);
                    input = s.substring(1);
                    hasil += input + firstLetter + "AN";
                    edittexthasil.setText(hasil.toString());
                } edittexthasil.setText(hasil.toString());
            }
```

**My Question is**

My input is "**hello world**"

But why my output is "**nullellohAN nullelloellohhAN** ",

and when i clicked the button again the output become " **nullelloellohhAN nullelloelloelloellohhAN**"

Why world part from hello world didn't show? just hello part.

And why theres too many null?

Why is changed everytime i clicked the butto? i want the input is stay like that ("**ellohAN orldwAN**") except when the input text is changed.

Theres no Error on Logcat, thats why i'm confused. Help me~

Comment: This is too much code to read...can you post just the relevant parts?

Comment: done, sorry for that

Comment: Does your internet provider charge by the letter? Pls expnd yr acrnyms.

Comment: This got **absolutely nothing** with encryption...

Comment: uh? so what should i do? @JonathanRosenne which acrnyms?

Comment: You should break the whole thing up into methods. For example, you should create a method which accepts one word an turns it into the desired output. `hasil = getHasil("hello"); // returns "ellohAN"` PS: this looks like pig latin.

Answer (score 0):

Is it some interview task? I'd advise you to pay more attention to code quality, not only to the final result. Regarding the errors you've listed - I see that you're trying to assign a String to String array:

```
String[] characterArray = word;
```

or create a String from an array:

```
wordArray[i] = new String(characterArray);
```

which are both illegal statements. Other ones are similar.

Try to use an IDE (like Eclipse or IDEA) which will show you those errors on the spot with advice on how to fix them. 
Also, if I were you I'd rethink the logic and rewrite the code from scratch :).

Comment: Other things: check equality using String.equals() Don't use == or !=. Also variables are only valid within the scope. In other words, you can't see them outside the { and } blocks. I was going to edit your code, but you need to learn the basics.

Comment: yeah, i should, but i'm still learning. from other answer/comment from another topic which is similar with this. but. . .my brain apparently didnt catch that. I just grab everything which i think is the code. . .i need time to understand. but then. i got deadline which is 9h later. so. . .